# How to sort numerical arrays that contain dashes? (JavaScript only)

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have this function to sort these phone numbers from the largest number to the smallest. It works fine when I remove the dashes within the numbers, but I'm supposed to make it work WITH the dashes included. So my question is whether or not it's possible to make my function ignore the dashes within the numbers?

```
var numberSorter=function(phoneNumbers){var organize=function(a, b){return b-a};
return phoneNumbers.sort(organize);}

var myNumbers=[914-954-1298, 914-954-1297, 954-914-1299]

console.log(numberSorter(myNumbers));
```

Comment: Just replace the `-` inside the sort function it will not effect the numbers in the array

Comment: `console.log([914-954-1298, 914-954-1297, 954-914-1299]);`

Comment: Well... first of all, those dashes are interpreted as minus signs (subtraction) so your phone numbers are just constant numbers, not as strings of numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can preserve the punctuation in the phone numbers, but ignore it when sorting. Just change the comparison function, `organize`, to compare stripped versions of the numbers, as strings. (You could use `parseInt()` to convert those strings to numbers if you wanted.)

Additional punctuation could be supported by changing the RegExp to strip typical dialing punctuation:

```
.replace(/[,()-]/g,"")
```

Or as pherris suggests, remove all non-digits with:

```
.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

You can run this snippet:

```js
var numberSorter=function(phoneNumbers){
  var organize=function(a, b){return a.replace(/-/g,"").localeCompare(b.replace(/-/g,""))};

  return phoneNumbers.sort(organize);
}

var myNumbers=['914-954-1298', '914-954-1297', '954-914-1299']

snippet.log(numberSorter(myNumbers));
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: this regex might be nicer - just replace all non digits: `"123 asdf234".replace(/\D/g, '');`

Answer (score 0):

Strings is the answer:

```js
var numberSorter = function(phoneNumbers) {
    var organize = function(a, b) {
        return b - a
    };
    return phoneNumbers.sort(organize);
}

var myNumbers = [
    '914-954-1298',
    '914-954-1297',
    '954-914-1299'
]

console.log(numberSorter(myNumbers));
```

Comment: That code doesn't sort the numbers properly.  The organize function will return NaN for any pair of those strings, because they cannot be coerced into numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Modern version of Mogsdad's answer:

```js
const numberSorterES6 = (phoneNumbers) => {
  return phoneNumbers.sort((a, b) => a.replace(/-/g, "") - b.replace(/-/g, ""));
}

const myNumbers=['914-954-1298', '914-954-1297', '954-914-1299']

console.log(numberSorterES6(myNumbers));
```

It just removes the dashes with `.replace(/-/g, "")` so it can sort them like normal numbers. If you want descending instead of ascending change the `-` to `+` in the sort function.